# Database dropdown list value printed on labels

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, dropdown

I'm using ASP.net to make a dropdown menu. The dropdown menu is linked to a database, all that works. If a value is selected in the dropdown, labels have to be filled that match the dropdown value in the database.
Hope I'm being clear, here's what I have so far :

```
    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
        conn.Open();
        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + Server.MapPath(@"\App_Data") + @"\JipEnJanneke.mdb";


        OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("Select (Prijs, Jaartal, ISBN) from JipEnJanneke where Titel = @Titel", conn);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Titel", DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString());
        OleDbDataReader rd = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
        while (rd.Read())
        {
            lbl_Prijs.Text = rd["Prijs"].ToString();
            lbl_Jaar.Text = rd["Jaartal"].ToString();
            lbl_Isbn.Text = rd["ISBN"].ToString();
        }
        conn.Close();
```

Unfortunately this leaves the labels empty. If I add the function to my page_load the labels do get filled, but for some reason only by the first value in the dropdown. A similair post on here suggested shoving it in the selectindexchanged, but that leaves it empty for me. Anyone got an idea?

Here's my page_load event right now

```
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + Server.MapPath(@"\App_Data") + @"\JipEnJanneke.mdb";
        //conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + Server.MapPath(@"\App_Data") + @"\JipEnJanneke.mdb";

        lblConnectionFeedback.Text = "";
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            lblConnectionFeedback.Text += "Connection is: " + conn.State.ToString();

            // HIER QUERY
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Boeken";

            OleDbDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            DropDownList1.DataSource = rd;
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Titel";
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Titel";
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
            rd.Close();

            conn.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            lblConnectionFeedback.Text = exc.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
            lblConnectionFeedback.Text += "<br />Connection is: " + conn.State.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your load event AND your code in the dropdown_selectedindexchanged, check the IsPostBack of the page. Ex :

```
    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
if (IsPostBack){
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
        conn.Open();
        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + Server.MapPath(@"\App_Data") + @"\JipEnJanneke.mdb";


        OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("Select (Prijs, Jaartal, ISBN) from JipEnJanneke where Titel = @Titel", conn);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Titel", DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString());
        OleDbDataReader rd = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
        while (rd.Read())
        {
            lbl_Prijs.Text = rd["Prijs"].ToString();
            lbl_Jaar.Text = rd["Jaartal"].ToString();
            lbl_Isbn.Text = rd["ISBN"].ToString();
        }
        conn.Close();
}
}
```

Load :

```
if (!IsPostBack){
   OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + Server.MapPath(@"\App_Data") + @"\JipEnJanneke.mdb";
        //conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + Server.MapPath(@"\App_Data") + @"\JipEnJanneke.mdb";

        lblConnectionFeedback.Text = "";
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            lblConnectionFeedback.Text += "Connection is: " + conn.State.ToString();

            // HIER QUERY
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Boeken";

            OleDbDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            DropDownList1.DataSource = rd;
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Titel";
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Titel";
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
            rd.Close();

            conn.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            lblConnectionFeedback.Text = exc.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
            lblConnectionFeedback.Text += "<br />Connection is: " + conn.State.ToString();
        }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting closer, but now I'm getting an error based on line 120, which is the               OleDbDataReader rd = cmd1.ExecuteReader(); line at my selectedindex. I need to keep it however because of the while statement...

Answer (score 0):

Please check that the AutoPostBack property of the DropDownList1 is set to True.